# How to closeAndClearTokenInformation with facebook sdk 4

Tags: java, android, facebook, sdk

I'm upgrading facebook sdk to 4.4.0
with the sdk 3.19.0 on the login process I've got this when I log out
"Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();" 
how I do this with sdk 4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just call this function to logout.

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logout();
```

This is the equivalent function for

```
Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
```